# Using llama-index loading Nodes into Weaviate Vector Store errors with TypeError: Object of type WindowsPath is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, weaviate, llama-index

I am following the llama-index tutorial  [Building Data Ingestion From Scratch](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/low_level/ingestion.html#load-data) which uses Pinecone to ingest the formatted nodes with

```
from llama_index.vector_stores import PineconeVectorStore
vector_store = PineconeVectorStore(pinecone_index=pinecone_index)
vector_store.add(nodes)
```

So I formatted this to use Weaviate instead

```
from llama_index.vector_stores import WeaviateVectorStore
# construct vector store
vector_store = WeaviateVectorStore(weaviate_client = client, index_name="SBCZoning")
vector_store.add(nodes)
```

But I receive a TypeError "WindowsPath" not serializable. See below

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [73], in <cell line: 6>()
      1 # nodes_to_parse = SimpleNodeParser.get_nodes_from_documents(nodes)
      2 # nodes_to_parse = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(nodes)
      3 
      4 # construct vector store
      5 vector_store = WeaviateVectorStore(weaviate_client = client, index_name="SBCZoning")
----> 6 vector_store.add(nodes)
      8 # setting up the storage for the embeddings
      9 storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store = vector_store)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\vector_stores\weaviate.py:181, in WeaviateVectorStore.add(self, nodes)
    179 with self._client.batch as batch:
    180     for node in nodes:
--> 181         add_node(
    182             self._client,
    183             node,
    184             self.index_name,
    185             batch=batch,
    186             text_key=self.text_key,
    187         )
    188 return ids

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\vector_stores\weaviate_utils.py:152, in add_node(client, node, class_name, batch, text_key)
    149 metadata = {}
    150 metadata[text_key] = node.get_content(metadata_mode=MetadataMode.NONE) or ""
--> 152 additional_metadata = node_to_metadata_dict(
    153     node, remove_text=True, flat_metadata=False
    154 )
    155 metadata.update(additional_metadata)
    157 vector = node.get_embedding()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\llama_index\vector_stores\utils.py:46, in node_to_metadata_dict(node, remove_text, text_field, flat_metadata)
     43 node_dict["embedding"] = None
     45 # dump remainder of node_dict to json string
---> 46 metadata["_node_content"] = json.dumps(node_dict)
     48 # store ref doc id at top level to allow metadata filtering
     49 # kept for backwards compatibility, will consolidate in future
     50 metadata["document_id"] = node.ref_doc_id or "None"  # for Chroma

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py:231, in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    226 # cached encoder
    227 if (not skipkeys and ensure_ascii and
    228     check_circular and allow_nan and
    229     cls is None and indent is None and separators is None and
    230     default is None and not sort_keys and not kw):
--> 231     return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
    232 if cls is None:
    233     cls = JSONEncoder

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py:199, in JSONEncoder.encode(self, o)
    195         return encode_basestring(o)
    196 # This doesn't pass the iterator directly to ''.join() because the
    197 # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198 # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199 chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200 if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201     chunks = list(chunks)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py:257, in JSONEncoder.iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    252 else:
    253     _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
    254         markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
    255         self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256         self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257 return _iterencode(o, 0)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py:179, in JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
    160 def default(self, o):
    161     """Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
    162     a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
    163     (to raise a ``TypeError``).
   (...)
    177 
    178     """
--> 179     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                     f'is not JSON serializable')

TypeError: Object of type WindowsPath is not JSON serializable
```

I have done exactly as the tutorial outlines ( Loading data from pdf with PyMuPDFReader(), Use SentenceSplitter over documents while maintaining relationship with source doc index, added Metadata using MetadataExtractor via llama_index.node_parser.extractors ...)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had specified the file path as Path() which I didn't realize the type Path would be included with every Node's metadata.
So from this

```
loader = PyMuPDFReader()
documents = loader.load(file_path=Path('data/sbc_zones.pdf'))
```

to this where I removed `Path`

```
loader = PyMuPDFReader()
documents = loader.load(file_path='data/sbc_zones.pdf')
```